Python no quiere importar una función que hice
Actualmente tengo la estructura de archivos así:
Source/
|-- domain/
|   |-- startProcess.py (adentro tengo una función llamada StartProcess)
|
|-- services/
|   |-- info_request.py (aquí quiero llamar la función StartProcess)

Adentro de info_request.py tengo este código:
from domain.startModel import StartProcess
Pero me sale "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'domain'"
Intente poner ".." antes de domain, es decir: from ..domain.startModel import StartProcess pero me sale "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"
Luego intente poner los __init__.py tanto en la carpeta domain y services pero igualmente me sale los 2 mensajes

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? No puedo importar paquetes en python
